# SQLCMD append file using -o

Tags: file, unicode, append, sqlcmd

I'm using sqlcmd to write query to file using the -o operator.
I want to append multiple writings to the same file, but using >> does not make a unicode file and creates a problem with special chars...

Operator >> appends the file correctly, but i need -o -u to get the right chars.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

The command line option `-f 65001` changes the file format to Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) using codepage 65001.